# JLabel text disappears in JPanel after resize

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jlabel

I have two renderers. One of them extends JTextArea and another inherits JPanel. I add them to another JPanel with GridBagLayout.

When a resize JTextArea I can see at least some text. In case of JPanel I have two labels and if JPanel is to small they disappear entirely.

Is there any way to make JLabel being resized instead of disappearing at all?

---

Thanks for your answers!

Using BoxLayout for JPanel and specifying minimum, preferred and maximum sizes solved my problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: what do you mean by "renderer"? Really a XXCellRenderer, vending a the panel as rendering component? If not, don't use the term, you'll confuse me ;-)

Comment: I mean that I have two components. One of them is JTextArea which works fine, because it shows at least some text if it could. JPanel hides the whole JLabel. Is than mean that I need to write my own code to resize each component in JPanel?

Comment: I have never seen this problem. The GridBagLayot uses the minimum size to help determine how to shrink components when not enough space is available to display a component at its preferred size. The minimum size of a JLabel is equal to its preferred size so a JLabel never shrinks in size. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem and maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using your frame's `setMinimumSize(Dimension)` method?

```
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
```

A look at the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) tells me that the behavior you're seeing is platform dependent, so if you have mutiple platforms, it may be a good idea to test out the code you have on each ones; see which ones work and which ones don't.

The following example code works for me as desired on Windows Vista:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Ex extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("YOU CAN'T SHRINK ME COMPLETELY!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

check the layout manager of the panel.

Comment: The question states that a GridBagLayout is being used.

Comment: he says that uses GridBagLayout for the outer panel, not for the one which contains the labels